# Is there a way to chopdown an html tag with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, emmet

I know that intellij has an html formatting setting for chopping down an html line if it is too long, but often I'm in the midst of editing and I need to add a lot of attributes to a tag and I would just like to chop down the tag with just a keyboard shortcut.  I've searched through the intellij settings. I can't find a way to do it other than manually.

just to clarify what I mean is I want to turn this:

```html
<input type="some-type" id="some-id" [someAngularProperty]="some fairly long bit of logic"/>
```

into this:

```html
<input 
  type="some-type" 
  id="some-id" 
  [someAngularProperty]="some fairly long bit of logic"
/>
```

with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `Ctrl+Alt+L` ('Reformat Code' action).

If you select a piece of code and hit the shortcut, it will reformat that piece for you according to current formatting settings (**File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**). If nothing is selected, it will reformat the whole file.

So in order for chopping down to take effect on hitting the shortcut, 'Wrapping attributes' option should be set to either 'Chop down if long' or 'Wrap always' (screenshot).

More information on reformatting and rearranging code in IntelliJ IDEA [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html).

[image]

Comment: I am aware of that shortcut. It doesn't do what I'm asking, unless, I guess, there's a way to set all html tags or all of a certain type to chop down, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Well, 'chopping down the tag' is part of the reformatting mechanism, and there are currently no other shortcuts / actions for it. You can look into [EditorConfig](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig) as an alternative to manage code style settings for each individual set of files, for instance.

Comment: That's close enough I guess.  I wish I knew a way to get it to put the closing braces `>` or `/>` on a new line when it did the wrapping.  I'm guessing I can create an .editorconfig file with that action.

Comment: You need the `ij_html_new_line_after_last_attribute = when multiline` option.